# Cual es la diferencia entre getbutton y getkey?

Tags: unity2d, game

Me gustaría saber la diferencia entre estos dos, ya que no lo termino de entender del todo.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que has investigado y qué es lo que no entiendes?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Vi uno de los videos oficiales de unity y es que getbutton usa etiquetas que representan alguna tecla predeterminada. Getkey usa keycodes para llamar directamente las teclas. Lo que no entiendo es la diferencia, ya sea en optimización o tal vez a la hora de usar  controles de consolas, cual es más cómodo y cual se recomienda?. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Vi uno de los videos oficiales de unity y es que getbutton usa etiquetas que representan alguna tecla predeterminada. Getkey usa keycodes para llamar directamente las teclas. Lo que no entiendo es la diferencia, ya sea en optimización o tal vez a la hora de usar  controles de consolas, cual es más cómodo y cual se recomienda?. Gracias